# How to return custom fields in GraphQL

Tags: craft3, graphql

This is definitely a noob question, but I can't seem to find an answer to this. (Completely new to GraphQL).

I'm trying to simply return entries:

```
query test {
  entries(section: "vacancies", limit: 20) {
    title
    expiryDate
    description
  }
}
```

Since the description is a custom field, this gives an error. How do I get a custom field value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything else than base element fields, you'll need to use an [inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments) to fetch your custom fields like so:

```
query test {
  entries(section: "vacancies", limit: 20) {
    title
    expiryDate
    ...on sectionHandle_entryTypeHandle_Entry {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `sectionHandle` and `entryTypeHandle` with your values, I guess something like `vacancies_vacancies_Entry`